# Exponentials of a matrix

Tags: matrices, control-theory

I just was working with matrix exponentials for solving problems in control theory. Suppose $A $ is a square matrix. How can we interpret $A_1 = e^ {\textstyle-A\log(t) }$, where $\log$ is natural logarithm? Is there a formula for extending the scalar case of $e^ {\textstyle-a\log(t) }$ which gives $\dfrac{1}{t^a}$? How do we evaluate $A_1$?

---

Here is how I proceeded along the lines of scalar case:

$$A_1 = \exp(-A\log t)) = \exp(-\log {t^A}) \overset{\textstyle?}{=}\;( t^A)^{-1}$$

Is the final equality correct?

Comment: 1. You will get better results if you put your thoughts in the question instead of an answer.  2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential

Comment: Usually in control-theory, the time does not show up in this way. For instance, for a linear system $\dot x = Ax$, the solution is $x(t) = x(0)e^{At}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the matrix exponential, more care is necessary. One approach is to multiply each item in the matrix $A$ by $\ln t$ and then find the diagonal matrix and take advantage of its structure.

Try working these two examples and see if you get them.

**Example 1:** Matrix is in diagonal form

$A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.

For a matrix of this type, we can take advantage of the fact that it is a diagonal matrix, and right away write out:

$\displaystyle e^{-A \ln t} = e^{\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0\\0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}*\ln t} =  \begin{bmatrix} 1/t & 0 \\ 0 & 1/t \end{bmatrix}$

**Example 2:** Diagonalizable Matrix

$A = \begin{bmatrix}-1 & -3\\-1 & -3\end{bmatrix}$, so

$\displaystyle e^{-A \ln t} = e^{\begin{bmatrix}1 & 3\\1 & 3 \end{bmatrix}*\ln t} = \begin{bmatrix}-3 & 1 \\ 1 & 1  \end{bmatrix} \cdot e^{\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 4 \ln t \end{bmatrix}}\cdot \begin{bmatrix} -1/4 & 1/4 \\ 1/4 & 3/4 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-3 & 1 \\ 1 & 1  \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & t^4 \end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix} -1/4 & 1/4 \\ 1/4 & 3/4 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{t^4}{4}+ \dfrac{3}{4} & \dfrac{3 t^4}{4}-\dfrac{3}{4} \\ \dfrac{t^4}{4}-\dfrac{1}{4} & \dfrac{3 t^4}{4} + \dfrac{1}{4}\end{bmatrix}$

**Example 3:** Non-diagonalizable Matrix

For this matrix, we will write it using the [*Jordan Normal Form*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) as $A = P \cdot J \cdot P^{-1}$ and take advantage of the Jordan block.

$A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 2\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$, so

$\displaystyle e^{-A \ln t} = e^{\begin{bmatrix}-1 & -2\\0 &-1 \end{bmatrix}*\ln t} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -\dfrac{1}{2}  \end{bmatrix} \cdot e^{\begin{bmatrix}-\ln t & \ln t \\ 0 & - \ln t \end{bmatrix}}\cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -\dfrac{1}{2}  \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{1}{t} & \dfrac{\ln t}{t} \\ 0 & \dfrac{1}{t} \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{1}{t} & -\dfrac{2 \ln t}{t} \\ 0 & \dfrac{1}{t} \end{bmatrix} $

**Example 4**

$A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

Give it a go. The matrix is diagonalizable and you should get:

$$e^{-A \ln t} = \frac{1}{15 t^3}\begin{bmatrix}4 t^5+5 t^2+6 & 2 t^5-5 t^2+3 & 6 (1-t^5) \\ ~~2 (2 t^5-5 t^2+3) & 2 t^5+10 t^2+3 & 6 (1-t^5) \\ ~~6 (1-t^5) & 3 (1-t^5) & 3 (3 t^5+2)\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: I thought post this might interest you! Excellent models!

Comment: @Amzoti Ok, thanks for the note, +1. Best.